# (VBA) For loop and DLookup (MS ACCESS)

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, msgbox

I have a query named **TimeQuery**. I want MsgBox will show all **[start_hour]** values where **[id]**=1 then 2 etc. ...
I have a problem. When i will use:

```
a = DLookup("Hour([start_hour])", "TimeQuery", "[id]=1")
```

it works good, but when use **[id]=counter** it doesn't show it. I have a MsgBox after that For Loop too and when **[id]=counter** it doesn't show that MsgBox too. What's wrong?

```
For counter = 1 To 3
Dim a As Variant
a = DLookup("Hour([start_hour])", "TimeQuery", "[id]=counter")
MsgBox (counter)
Next
Debug.Print ("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate your variable to a string if you want to use this, like so:

```
For counter = 1 To 3
    Dim a As Variant

    a = DLookup("Hour([start_hour])", "TimeQuery", "[id]=" & counter)
    MsgBox (counter)

Next

Debug.Print ("")
```

However, if you want to do this properly, use recordsets

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("SELECT Hour([start_hour]) As hr FROM TimeQuery WHERE [id] <=3 ORDER BY ID ASC")
Do While Not rs.EOF
   MsgBox rs!hr
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```